# SQL Server import table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, ssis

I tried to upload a table (contains Latin characters) to SQL Server and I got this message. Can someone help me?

- Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Description" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Description" (14)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Description" (14)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\rinaldo.tempo\Desktop\ICD10_Edition4_CodesAndTitlesAndMetadata_GB_20120401.txt" on data row 3.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)  Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - ICD10_Edition4_CodesAndTitlesAndMetadata_GB_20120401_txt" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: How did you import it? What settings, etc. can you provide some sample data? What's the terminator and delimiter?

Comment: What are you try first ? What is your code ? any asit reach me at sujayb7@@gmail.com

Comment: I fixed that, did't know that have tho change the size of the filed twice...
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

on your data flow task, the field Description is being truncated. you can increase the size of this field. go into your flat files connection mgr and increase the size of the field under the advanced tab. the default here should be 50 chars. make sure your destination table and this value are the same. I would suggest varchar(200) for testing if the max size of Description is not yet known.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and succeeded.
I uploaded about 1,5M  rows, and than the upload stopped and I got this message

Comment: (Error) Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Unspecified error". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination - Products.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[ProductID] on Destination - Products.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column

Comment: Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Destination - Products.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Products.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Products" (38) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (51). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Hi, I'm glad that worked for you. does your column allow nulls? sounds like you have a constraint on that column.